# Python Kivy: Search directory for filetype

Tags: python, kivy, file-search

There are many ways, to search a dir for containing a string, that's not really my question. But is there something built in for Python Kivy, that allows automatically searching for files (*.mp3) in a directory with subdirs, or do I have to create one on my own?
If I have to do so, how do I get all the files and subdirs in a directory?

Thank you :)

**Finally I decided coding the needed function on my own:**

```
import os
def listfiles(path):
     files = []
     for base, directory, filename in os.walk(path):
          for i in range(len(filename)):
               files.append(base+"/"+filename[i])
     return files
print(listfiles("/path/path/"))
```

Checking files for extensions should be easy enaugh :)

***Unfortunately the process might take very long for bigger directories, so I'm still looking for a different solution.***

Comment: you might want to check out kivy.uix.filechooser FileChooser

Comment: I guess filechooser lets the user pick a file, instead of searching several ones?

Comment: I edited my tread now, to make sure everyone knows, what I mean :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Kivy `kivy.uix.filechooser` `FileChooserController` and its method `files`

> The list of files in the directory specified by path after applying the filters.
>
> files is a read-only ListProperty.

@edit

Here's what I also found in Kivy docs and this one seems even nicer:

```
from kivy.uix.filechooser import FileSystemLocal
file_system = FileSystemLocal()
file_system.listdir('/path/to/dir')   # this returns a list of files in dir
```

Instead of `FileSystemLocal` you can also use `FileSystemAbstract` if you are not going to browse only local files.

Comment: Could you please give an example for searching "/dir/dir2" for "*.txt" or something?

Comment: sure just give me a couple of minutes to write it down

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't search through the subdirs. I'm looking for a way, to list all files in a directory and all its subdirectories.

Comment: for that I'm afraid you will need to write your own loop iterating through all subdirs

Answer (score 0):

```
files = [] # list with files in directory
suff = ('.mp3', '.wav')
for i in files:
    if i.endswith(suff):
        print files
```

[Suffixes needs to be tuples](http://bugs.python.org/issue13755) for this to work.